# Why isn't the same font isn't looking the same with same font-weight?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

I want to recode [this template](https://colorlib.com/preview/theme/amado/) as a practice.
I downloaded its font "HelveticaNeue Medium"
But with my code it looks bolder than the original template
here's my code and I want to achieve thinner one

Original look, what I want to achieve:

[image: Original look, what I want to achieve]

Looking bolder with my code:

[image: Looking bolder with my code]

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueMedium";
  src: url("../fonts/helveticaneuemedium-webfont.eot"); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url("../fonts/helveticaneuemedium-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url("../fonts/helveticaneuemedium-webfont.otf") format("opentype"), /* Open Type Font */
    url("../fonts/helveticaneuemedium-webfont.svg") format("svg"), /* Legacy iOS */
    url("../fonts/helveticaneuemedium-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url("../fonts/helveticaneuemedium-webfont.woff") format("woff"), /* Modern Browsers */
    url("../fonts/helveticaneuemedium-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"); /* Modern Browsers */
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
.container .content .sidebar .menu-wrapper .main-menu .main-menu-links{
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeueMedium', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: .9;
  font-weight: 50;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="menu-wrapper">
<ul class="main-menu">
            <li class="main-menu-item"><a class="main-menu-links" href="#">Home<a/></li>
            <li class="main-menu-item"><a class="main-menu-links" href="#">Shop<a/></li>
            <li class="main-menu-item"><a class="main-menu-links" href="#">Product<a/></li>
            <li class="main-menu-item"><a class="main-menu-links" href="#">Cart<a/></li>
            <li class="main-menu-item"><a class="main-menu-links" href="#">Checkout<a/></li>
          </ul>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: They're not at the same weight. The "template" has it at `font-weight: 400` and you have it at `font-weight: 50`.

Comment: Thank you, but that "font-weight: 50" was my last attempt to get the appropriate result :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect from answerers when you title your question "same font at same weight" and then show code with the same font at a different weight... If you say 50 == 400, computers are going to say false, and coders are going to say, "the computer's going to tell you that's false". [Edit] your question so that either your title matches the code, or the code matches the title.

Answer (score 0):

be careful you wrote `<a/>` instead of `</a>`.

Using WhatFont, the `font-weight` isn't 50 but 400.

[image: WhatFont result]

Maybe your browser considered your 50 as 500, the reason it look likes bolder. You can try this :

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeueMedium";
  src: url("../fonts/helveticaneuemedium-webfont.eot"); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url("../fonts/helveticaneuemedium-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url("../fonts/helveticaneuemedium-webfont.otf") format("opentype"), /* Open Type Font */
    url("../fonts/helveticaneuemedium-webfont.svg") format("svg"), /* Legacy iOS */
    url("../fonts/helveticaneuemedium-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url("../fonts/helveticaneuemedium-webfont.woff") format("woff"), /* Modern Browsers */
    url("../fonts/helveticaneuemedium-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"); /* Modern Browsers */
}

body{
  background-color: white;
}

.container .content .sidebar .menu-wrapper .main-menu .main-menu-links{
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeueMedium', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: .9;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="content">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="menu-wrapper">
          <ul class="main-menu">
            <li class="main-menu-item"><a class="main-menu-links" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="main-menu-item"><a class="main-menu-links" href="#">Shop</a></li>
            <li class="main-menu-item"><a class="main-menu-links" href="#">Product</a></li>
            <li class="main-menu-item"><a class="main-menu-links" href="#">Cart</a></li>
            <li class="main-menu-item"><a class="main-menu-links" href="#">Checkout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jerome W. I was informed of "font-weight: 50" that was my last attempt to get the results :D but I didn't know about "a" tags. so I corrected them but no difference!